# about fetching the exact integer value from SQLite database by making some query

Tags: android-studio-3.4

I Have a problem to fetch the data(item value and how to compare this item with anoher pagefrom SQLiteData Base ?

Cursor c=sq.rawQuery("select ClientId from RequestDriver where Date=? and FromTime=? and ToTime=?",null);
        while(c.moveToNext()) {

```
        int req=Integer.parseInt(reqId);
        int ftime=Integer.parseInt(fromt);
        int ttime=Integer.parseInt(tot);
        int x=ttime-ftime;
        int ty = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ClientId"));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AssignDriver.class);


        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: answer as soon as possible

Comment: When you say "exact integer value", can you show us an example of an integer value from your database, as well as what you get back? In other words, what is the problem with your code exactly?

Comment: i want to retrive the the value from SQlitedatabase. How can i retreive it